# Pandas drop() method failing to drop column despite conventional wisdom on the subject

Tags: python, pandas

I've seen the various threads where pandas' .drop() fails because the user fails to either specify the inplace argument or re-declare the dataframe using the drop method, or because the user fails to set the axis argument to 1.

Well, I have tried every possible correction I can think of (including renaming the index so that it no longer shares the name of the column I'm trying to drop, re-declaring the dataframe with all the columns except the one I'm trying to drop, etc.), and the column still won't drop!

```
t_start_pd = time.time();\

for i in augmenting_dfs:
    #if there is no leadoff "Symbol" column, we will need to add this column via broadcasting and order the cols so this col is first
    if i.shape[1] == 7:
        i['symbol'] = symbol
        i = i.loc[:, ['symbol', 'Date', 'Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'TotalVolume']]#order our cols as other DF cols are
    i.columns = ['symbol', 'price_date', 'price_time', 'price_open', 'price_high', 'price_low', 'price_close', 'volume']
    print('Columns formatted.')
    i['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(i.price_date.astype('str') + ' ' + i.price_time.astype('str'))
    print('datetime formatted')
    i.index = i.datetime
    i = i.drop('datetime', axis = 1)
    
t_end_pd = time.time()

print(t_end_pd - t_start_pd)
```

The print statements included show that, within the for loop, at least, the column in question is successfully dropped.

```
Columns formatted.
datetime formatted
Index(['symbol', 'price_date', 'price_time', 'price_open', 'price_high',
       'price_low', 'price_close', 'volume', 'datetime'],
      dtype='object')
Index(['symbol', 'price_date', 'price_time', 'price_open', 'price_high',
       'price_low', 'price_close', 'volume'],
      dtype='object')
Columns formatted.
datetime formatted
Index(['symbol', 'price_date', 'price_time', 'price_open', 'price_high',
       'price_low', 'price_close', 'volume', 'datetime'],
      dtype='object')
Index(['symbol', 'price_date', 'price_time', 'price_open', 'price_high',
       'price_low', 'price_close', 'volume'],
      dtype='object')
Columns formatted.
datetime formatted
Index(['symbol', 'price_date', 'price_time', 'price_open', 'price_high',
       'price_low', 'price_close', 'volume', 'datetime'],
      dtype='object')
Index(['symbol', 'price_date', 'price_time', 'price_open', 'price_high',
       'price_low', 'price_close', 'volume'],
      dtype='object')
```

However, when I access one of these supposedly transformed dataframes outside of the for loop...

```
augmenting_dfs[0].columns
```

...the datetime column I tried to drop is back, risen from the dead.

```
Index(['symbol', 'price_date', 'price_time', 'price_open', 'price_high',
       'price_low', 'price_close', 'volume', 'datetime'],
      dtype='object')
```

I've tried accomplishing the same transformation outside of a for loop with a list comprehension, but like everything I've tried, it just can't seem to get rid of this column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd   
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((3,3)), columns=[*'ABC'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((3,3)), columns=[*'ABC'])

ldfs = [df1, df2]

for i in ldfs:
    i.set_index('A', inplace=True)
print(ldfs[0])
```

Output:

```
       B    C
A            
1.0  1.0  1.0
1.0  1.0  1.0
1.0  1.0  1.0
```

Comment: This works, though sadly, it does not work when using i = i.set_index('A') instead of what you have using the inplace argument. I would have preferred something along the lines of the former, as this would also be compatible with Dask, whose .set_index() method does not support the inplace argument.

Answer (score 0):

You modify temporary variable `i` (it exist only in the scope of the for loop) but is not changing value of the element in the list.

You can check on simple example:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [7, 8, 9], 'b': [0, 1, 2]})
dfs = [df1, df2]

for df in dfs:
    df = df.drop('a', axis=1)

print(dfs[0])

dfs = [df.drop('a', axis=1) for df in dfs]

print(dfs[0])
```

results are:

```
   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
   b
0  4
1  5
2  6
```

Seconde aproach reasign list of modified values.

Comment: I tried to implement your idea by altering the for loop so that it only creates the datetime column and creates an index from it, then using the list comprehension to drop the column in question the way you have it above. I got thrown the following error: KeyError: "['datetime'] not found in axis". This makes absolutely NO SENSE to me since, as I mentioned, I removed any code that attempted to drop the column in the for loop, so the datetime column is still unquestionably there. So I have no idea why it would say it can't find datetime in axis, as we haven't even tried to remove it yet.

Comment: You should follow error trace to track what cause this problem. It's hard to say without it and modified code to guess but I think you might introduce another bug.